# Best way to implement sort, search & pagination with Redis for maximum performance

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I have large data approx 1,00,000 for employee. I have stored this data to one Redis key called "employess". Now there is one screen where I would like to perform search on some field & sort on each column along with pagination.

So for that I have created following code that works fine. but it takes time around 1.2 seconds to 2 seconds average.

I would like to reduce it to 200 milliseconds **( requirement )**

Can somebody guide me how can I achieve that performance or what I am doing wrong in following code.

I am working with C# code & ServiceStack.Redis client. I am free to use any other Redis client if requires.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

// Methods that handles sort,search,paging & getting data form Redis.

```
  private GeneralResponse<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmp(SearchParam filter, int initialPage, int pageSize, out int totalRecords, out int recordFilterd,
           int sortColumn, string sortDirection)
        {
            var response = new GeneralResponse<IEnumerable<Employee>>();
            totalRecords = 0;
            recordFilterd = 0;

            try
            {
                var data = Enumerable.Empty<Employee>().AsQueryable();
                try
                {
                    using (var redisClient = new RedisClient(Common.redisUrl, Common.redisPort))
                    {


                        var rdata = redisClient.Get<IEnumerable<Employee>>("employess");
                        data = rdata.AsQueryable();
                        ViewBag.source = "redis";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    data = Common.EmployeesList.AsQueryable();
                    ViewBag.source = "Database";
                }


                totalRecords = data.Count();
                //filter 
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.FirstName))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x =>
                        x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(filter.FirstName.Trim().ToLower())
                    );

                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.LastName))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x =>
                        x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(filter.LastName.Trim().ToLower())
                    );
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Department))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x =>
                        x.Department.ToLower() == filter.Department.Trim().ToLower()
                    );
                }
                if (filter.FromDob != null && filter.FromDob != default(DateTime))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x => x.DOB >= filter.FromDob);
                }
                if (filter.ToDob != null && filter.ToDob != default(DateTime))
                {
                    filter.ToDob = filter.ToDob.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);
                    data = data.Where(x => x.DOB <= filter.ToDob);

                }
                recordFilterd = data.Count();

                //sort 
                var ascending = sortDirection == "asc";
                switch (sortColumn)
                {
                    case 0:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.EmployeeId, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.LastName, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.FirstName, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.DOB, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Gender, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Street, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.City, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.State, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Zip, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Department, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Occupation, ascending);
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Occupation, ascending);
                        break;
                    default:
                        data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Salary, ascending);
                        break;
                }

                data = data
                    .Skip(initialPage * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);

                var result = data.ToList();
                response.Data = result;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                response.Error = true;
                response.Exception = e;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated. following is the reference screen where I wanted to achieve the speed.

[image]

Comment: Did you check redisearch.io?

Comment: You need to create indexes for those properties you want to filter. Take a look at https://redis.io/topics/indexes. You can also use Lua scripts, Redis' equivalent of stored procedures, to move some of the processing server-side.

Comment: var rdata = redisClient.Get<IEnumerable<Employee>>("employess");
                        data = rdata.AsQueryable(); -- what is the type of rdata I assume that this is already some kind of List and you take all data in your local memory and perform other operations like filtering and other stuff.! You need to setup indexes for properties which you want to search or order is how it works for SQL Server not sure about Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep research, I finally found that Redis is not good option for performing these operation. Rather than this we can go for AWS CloudSearch which has full capabilities for Sort,Search & Pagination.

Comment: you asked exactly what I was going to ask. With AWS Cloud Search, are you basically feeding that with your data in json format? are you using cloud search as your main database? Or if you are using it for only caching purposes, when there is any CRUD to existing db, are you just reflecting that piece of data on AWS Cloud search? I would appreciate if you can shed some light. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned above in comments and in your answer, redis may not be the best option for this problem, and AWS CloudSearch could be the solution.

When solving a similar issue, I found that my biggest bottleneck was using 'query.Where(x => x.String.Contains(filterText))`.

Adding a full text index onto text-searched columns (first/last name for your solution) allowed us to go to SQL directly with satisfactory performance (100-200ms for a ~1 million row table). https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9136/sql-server-full-text-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you add for each indexed document an integer **int_id** you can execute the following query : '@**int_id**:[1 10]'. This query select all documents between  1-10.

more infos: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Query_Syntax.html